# How to create pull request with unmerged pull request?

Tags: git, github

I branched out of latest `master` to create `my-branch`. There is `other-branch` that is pending pull request.
I need `other-branch` for my code to compile. So, I pulled `other-branch` into `my-branch`. I added some code and committed it in `my-branch`. Now, I want to create a pull request.
In the pull request, how can I show only my commit's diff?

steps I took:

1. brached out of `master` and created `my-branch`
2. pulled `other-branch` into `my-branch` ( basically merged)
3. commited by changes (I only have one commit, lets say its hash is: 032321)
4. I did `git cherry-pick 032321`
5. git push origin `my-branch`

For some reason pull request show diff from both `my-branch` and `other-branch`. But, I only wanted to show diff from `my-branch` i.e. commit of hash 032321.

Comment: Git does not have pull requests, so the short answer is "you can't". Some hosting sites *do* have pull requests and the details will depend on which one you're using: for GitHub in particular, select a branch in which your PR is already merged as the "base branch".

Comment: If I choose `other-branch` as base branch then it shows all the new commits that in `master`  but are not in `other-branch` which I do not want.

Comment: Make a *third* branch in the GitHub repository, where `other-branch`'s changes are merged (but further commits on master are not). Then use that as the base branch. Of course, merging the PR into that third branch is not what you want, but that's what you get here; but after the PR gets reviewed, *and* the `other-branch` is formally merged—you'll need both of these anyway—you can then *rebase* this branch on the merged result and have it re-reviewed, which should be easier than the initial review.